# Update statement in python SQLite3 with several variables

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

So I have the following statement

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE IllnessTable SET (?) = (?) WHERE IllnessName = (?)",      
(self.SymptomName,self.IllnessStatus[ControlVar],CurrentIllnessName))
```

where self.SymptomName is a String, self.IllnessStatus[ControlVar] is an integer and CurrentIllnessName is a string. The variables exist and correspond directly to my table. I'm wondering what's wrong with this SQL statement itself as I just get:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `?` placeholder only for literals, not for identifiers such as column names. Use string formatting in your programming language to produce a SQL with the identifiers you want.

Also, enclosing the `?` in parens is not necessary.

Therefore, change to something like:

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE IllnessTable SET {} = ? WHERE IllnessName = ?".format(self.SymptomName),      
(self.IllnessStatus[ControlVar],CurrentIllnessName))
```

Comment: What if SymptomName can change, what would I do then? Because what's happening is I'm allowing the program user to create a row and then update the contents of it for each column, where the row name is self.SymptomName.

Comment: Format the query string to contain the dynamic column name in python then.